# How can I export (to store) an ecdsa key pair in Rust?

Tags: rust, private-key, public-key, ecdsa

I am able to create a public/private ecdsa key in Rust, how can I store the keys for further use? I can't seem to find a method that will export the key.

```rs
use p256::{ecdsa::{SigningKey, Signature, signature::Signer}};
use rand_core::OsRng; // requires 'getrandom' feature

fn main() {
    // Signing
    let signing_key = SigningKey::random(&mut OsRng); // Serialize with `::to_bytes()`
    let message = b"ECDSA proves knowledge of a secret number in the context of a single message";
    let signature = signing_key.sign(message);


    // Verification
    use p256::ecdsa::{VerifyingKey, signature::Verifier};

    let verifying_key = VerifyingKey::from(&signing_key); // Serialize with `::to_encoded_point()`
    assert!(verifying_key.verify(message, &signature).is_ok());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many different ways to represent keys. Internally, it's a byte array that can be dumped as such directly. But for compatibility, you probably want a more standardized, human readable format.

The most common one is the [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) format.

To get a PEM, you cannot construct `SigningKey` and `VerifyingKey` directly. You need to create a `SecretKey` and a `PublicKey`. They can be stored and loaded to/from the PEM format.

You can then convert the `SecretKey` to a `SigningKey` and the `PublicKey` to a `VerifyingKey`.

Be aware that you need to enable the `pem` feature for the `p256` dependency:

```ini
p256 = { version = "0.11", features = ["pem"] }
```

```
use p256::{
    ecdsa::{
        signature::{Signer, Verifier},
        SigningKey, VerifyingKey,
    },
    pkcs8::EncodePrivateKey,
    PublicKey, SecretKey,
};
use rand_core::OsRng;

fn main() {
    // Generate secret key
    let secret_key = SecretKey::random(&mut OsRng);

    // Store secret key
    let secret_key_serialized = secret_key
        .to_pkcs8_pem(Default::default())
        .unwrap()
        .to_string();
    println!("Secret Key: \n{}", secret_key_serialized);

    // Load secret key
    let secret_key = secret_key_serialized.parse::<SecretKey>().unwrap();

    // Derive public key
    let public_key = secret_key.public_key();

    // Store public key
    let public_key_serialized = public_key.to_string();
    println!("Public Key: \n{}", public_key_serialized);

    // Load public key
    let public_key = public_key_serialized.parse::<PublicKey>().unwrap();

    // Signing
    let signing_key: SigningKey = secret_key.into();
    let message = b"ECDSA proves knowledge of a secret number in the context of a single message";
    let signature = signing_key.sign(message);

    // Verification
    let verifying_key: VerifyingKey = public_key.into();
    assert!(verifying_key.verify(message, &signature).is_ok());
}
```

```
Secret Key: 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQguKslF8gIC/Fm36Yk
SK2qZ4MXbUg/ZwCJwY9OmzRzkOehRANCAAQrRw99abOvHAPdz79CkuihXfaKZqx+
ZUG6iQRDzZy0c+gw20KeevA4gXKnW0nFK8PDmOgBprCU/uHf4vpMbqgo
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Public Key: 
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEK0cPfWmzrxwD3c+/QpLooV32imas
fmVBuokEQ82ctHPoMNtCnnrwOIFyp1tJxSvDw5joAaawlP7h3+L6TG6oKA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible format is the export as *raw* keys. The private key is 32 bytes for P-256 (aka secp256r1, prime256v1), the public key is 65 bytes (uncompressed) or 33 bytes (compressed), s. e.g. [here](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-messages#key-generation).

`signing_key` can be exported as raw private key with `to_bytes()` and `verifying_key` can be exported as an uncompressed/compressed public key with `to_encoded_point(false/true)`. `false` returns an uncompressed key, `true` a compressed one. Usually the keys are then hex or Base64 encoded, s. [here](https://docs.rs/p256/latest/src/p256/ecdsa.rs.html#61) (with sample data):

```rust
...
println!("{}", hex::encode(signing_key.to_bytes()));                // 3ee21644150adb50dc4c20e330184fabf12e75ecbf31fe167885587e6ebf2255
println!("{}", hex::encode(verifying_key.to_encoded_point(false))); // 044e6dbeefb3ffbab80281596869352fd4e90353758c3955914be90f0849d16aed5cefb4d5d4e209efaf8eb9349eed862c816cba3f2188e07d101f6ba2e23a69e9
println!("{}", hex::encode(verifying_key.to_encoded_point(true)));  // 034e6dbeefb3ffbab80281596869352fd4e90353758c3955914be90f0849d16aed
...
```

---

For completeness: The import of the private key is possible with `SigningKey::from_bytes()` and that of the uncompressed/compressed public key with `VerifyingKey::from_encoded_point()`.